# ZF2 Query with REGEXP

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, where-clause

In my application I want to select all the rows where a specific ID is in.

e.g. db structure

```
| video_id | video_title | actor_ids |
      1          Elia       3;4;5;6
      2         Avatar      4;8;9;23
```

I want to select every row who has the actor_ids=4. I use the follow query in my mysql workbench which works OK for this situation

```
SELECT *  FROM  `videos` WHERE  `video_actor_ids` REGEXP 4;
```

I would like to translate this query to a ZF2 query. I just need how to
translate it to a where clause. Can't find anything about REGEXP in the documentation.

Other solutions to do this select are (with better performance) are welcome too!

Thanks in advance,

nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind when I see something like "3;4;5;6" is not REGEXP, but normalization. I am convinced that you should rethink the way you handle your relations. In this particular case it is many-to-many type of relation. Do yourself a favour: get rid of the "3;4;5;6" as soon as possible.

Comment: So you suggest a 3th table to anchor each actor to a video? In this case I think for large database it shouldn't be the best for performance?.

Comment: On the contrary, it will be just fine. Just make sure you have added the index.

Comment: I used the method once already you suggest, it's true still fast with the right index. I thought I could be better for performance to do it like I did in this example but now I see, your are totally right. I change the structure :) Thanks a lot